# How can I subdivide on only one axis?

Tags: modeling, particles, vertices, selection-tools, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to use a weight-map to put columns of spines on a cactus. I need more vertices for the spines to spawn at on my model, but if I subdivide normally, it will create vertices in between the columns that are close enough to generate spines in the middle, which means I would have to manually modify the weight-map to remove the middle spines. Is there any work-around where I can create more vertices on the columns and not on the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove some loops after a subdivision, it can be relatively easy:

Switch to edit mode, edge select.  Select a ring loop by ctrl alt selecting on an edge:

[image]

Use a checker deselect operation to deselect every other edge:

[image]

Use select edge loops operation to select the loops from selected edges:

[image]

Then dissolve the edge loops:

[image]

Note that what is a column and what is a row is not particularly clear cut.  With two edge loops selected, which of those loops is a row and which is a column?

[image]

Any mesh with any poles-- which is every manifold mesh-- confuses the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the specific edges you would like to subdivide whilst in edit mode.